# Infrared camera simulation

Tags: camera

I am trying to create synthetic data for my NN.

I have to simulate an infrared camera but I don't know how.

Can you tell me if it is possible to do it with blender or not?

If it's possible, can you tell me how to do it( I am absolutely new with blender so it, will be nice if you explained every step.)

Also, I would be pleased to listen if you know any app that can simulate it(even paid apps) or any simulator.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "Simulate Infrared"? Please provide reference images if possible.

Comment: yea sure here its [Infrared image](https://electromagnetic-spectrum-pdl-er.weebly.com/uploads/2/3/6/6/23660328/2661857_orig.jpg). I want to capture images like this. In infrared images colors are based on object temperature and its radiance

Comment: Physically accurate simulations or something is not possible. I mean you can do smoke simulations and stuff and use the velocity to map it between blue and red colours. (But these are not actual infrared simulations or anything) Other than that just gradients between blue and red using different objects is possible. But that might be a lot of manual work depending on your situation. In thatt case, provide more details about yor situation. Like what exactly do you want to achieve. You might get a proper answer after that

Comment: thanks for your answer. We have a drone and we are trying to control it at night. The problem is object detection at night so we want have to create/get more data for our NN to detect better in IR mode then we can control it really easy. if its not possible to simulate accurately it wont be useful for me. Thanks again :)